# Как избавиться от дубликатов в Left Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица RaspisanieZanyatij:

```
id  KursNazvanie             VremyaNachala
1   Matematica                1300000000
5   БазоваяИнформатика        1312345678
6   Биология                  1318765432
4   География                 1322222222
2   История                   1300000000
3   Литература                1311111111
```

Я хочу вывести, чтобы значения шли **таким образом**:

```
1300000000  1311111111
1311111111  1312345678
1312345678  1318765432
1318765432  1322222222
1322222222  NULL
```

То есть я хочу вывести "значение - значение, немного большее"

Но мой код:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    --i1.id,
    i1.VremyaNachala AS time,
    i2.VremyaNachala AS greater_time
FROM
    RaspisanieZanyatij AS i1
    LEFT JOIN  RaspisanieZanyatij AS i2 ON   i2.VremyaNachala > i1.VremyaNachala
```

Выдаёт дубликаты:

```
1300000000  1311111111
1300000000  1312345678
1300000000  1318765432
1300000000  1322222222
1311111111  1312345678
1311111111  1318765432
1311111111  1322222222
1312345678  1318765432
1312345678  1322222222
1318765432  1322222222
1322222222  NULL
```

Как можно исправить код, чтобы убрать дубликаты слева и выводить лишь наименьшее большее справа ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.VremyaNachala, t2.VremyaNachala
FROM RaspisanieZanyatij t1
LEFT JOIN RaspisanieZanyatij t2 ON t1.VremyaNachala < t2.VremyaNachala
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                   FROM RaspisanieZanyatij t3
                   WHERE t1.VremyaNachala < t3.VremyaNachala
                     AND t3.VremyaNachala < t2.VremyaNachala )
```

или

```sql
SELECT t1.VremyaNachala, MIN(t2.VremyaNachala) VremyaNachala
FROM RaspisanieZanyatij t1
LEFT JOIN RaspisanieZanyatij t2 ON t1.VremyaNachala < t2.VremyaNachala
GROUP BY t1.VremyaNachala
```

и ещё куча вариантов...

Comment: существует ли отладка при написании запроса?Буквально увидеть, что сравнивается в 't1.VremyaNachala < t2.VremyaNachala'. Я подключал отладчик VS к базе данных, но он рассматривает запрос как одно целое, и нет возможности увидеть, что происходит внутри запроса

Comment: @Elvin *существует ли отладка при написании запроса?* Нет. *увидеть, что сравнивается в 't1.VremyaNachala < t2.VremyaNachala'.* Чудес не бывает, а у сервера полностью отсутствует инициатива - тем более чёрное чувство юмора. Будь уверен - что написано, то и сравнивается.